# Diskspace on OpenWRT router

Tags: linux, router, partitioning, openwrt, netgear-router

I bought this [router](https://openwrt.org/toh/netgear/netgear_r6220) which should have 128 MB of disk space.

Yet after installation of relevant release of OpenWRT I can only see 18MB:

```
% df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                 2.8M      2.8M         0 100% /rom
tmpfs                    60.5M      1.1M     59.4M   2% /tmp
/dev/ubi0_1              18.3M     11.7M      5.6M  67% /overlay
overlayfs:/overlay       18.3M     11.7M      5.6M  67% /
tmpfs                   512.0K         0    512.0K   0% /dev
```

Is this just a matter of configuration, a partition is too small (hard to check, somehow I do not have `block` command available that OpenWRT docs recommend to check for this)? If the disk is actually bigger, how to extend it?

Comment: Hmm, the router I'm using has cf-cards for flash space storage. No matter the size card I use, the OS is on a 128mb or 256mb partition. I then have to extend it to the full capacity using gparted in a Linux pc. It sounds like that is what's going on here.

Comment: Have you asked this over at the openwrt.com forums? I'm guessing you will find partitioning software within the webui side of opkg. If you wind up being stuck with the flash space like this, I might suggest plugging a USB stick in and installing the packages you want on that.

Comment: Honestly, you should do that anyway. **Note: that 60.5+2.8+18.3+18.3=99.9MB** this isn't going to leave you with alot of usable space, even if you do extend the flash space.